# Control multiple raspberries from a single web server

Tags: python, web, server, raspberry-pi3

Hello guys I want a help with my project.
As an electrical engineer I have implemented a project to control the AC 220V in my house.

The requirements:
Is it possible to control multiple raspberries in the same network from web page, with a single web server

Thanks

The components of the project are :
1x raspberry pi 3 
1x 4 relay module 
4x 220 power outlets

Thanks !!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: can you be more specific on "control multiple raspberry"? what kind of functions or features do you want to control on multiple raspberry pi?

Comment: Please check now thanks for help

Comment: The question is too broad and unclear. 1) Do you have the web page? You want to build it? Are you asking for a website that is already there and gives you the potential to control your raspberries? 2) You need to tell us if you have done something already. If you're just looking for advice on how to do such a thing, I suggest you to ask on the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have created only the hardware implementation and I want o build the website and the communication between web server and raspberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web server: this serves displaying data from raspberry pis and take actions to make calls to each raspberry pi

Ref: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md

Every raspberry pi will have some kind of API server which will execute scripts and deliver data to web server

GPIO: python script which will execute or read GPIO data upon api calls from web server

Ref: http://wiringpi.com/

API server on each raspberry pi - will listen to Web server's call to execute any execution call - java, python, php anything you are familiar with

Ref: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/

You need to change names on each raspberry pi to identify them.

Ref: https://www.howtogeek.com/167195/how-to-change-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-devices-hostname/

From web server, look it up names and ips, and then hook it up with web server pages to make right calls and display data.

Ref

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24338/how-to-control-multiple-raspberry-pis-at-once-over-ethernet

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46435/controlling-multiple-pis-over-a-network/46442

Comment: Can you explain this ?? In many cases the web server was installed in the raspberry. How can change it ? To create one web server for multiple raspberries Every raspberry pi will have some kind of API server which will execute scripts and deliver data to web server

Comment: added references for each section